# Is there any keyboard shortcut to add bookmarks in Safari?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, safari, shortcut

I am simply fed-up of adding bookmarks in Safari by long pressing the plus icon beside the safari omni-box so is there any one key keyboard shortcut to add bookmarks in Safari?

Comment: Did you look in the Bookmarks menu before asking this question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To add a bookmark:
`⌘ + d`

To add a shortcut to the Bookmark menu:
 `⌘ + shift + D`